# Modifying one object in arraylist changes its copy

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two objects of same class in Activity, say *User*. I created two objects *user* and *editedUser*. To avoid same reference problems, I created both of them from a JSON string using Google Gson. These classes contain ArrayLists that hold other objects, eg Degrees.

My problem is that, when I update one field in a Degree object in the ArrayList of *editedUser* it automatically reflected in the *user* object too. How can I avoid this?

Here is my code

Creating objects:

```
user = new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("userdata"), User.class);
editedUser = new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("userdata"), User.class);
```

and I modified it using this line

```
editedUser.getDegrees().get(0).setTitle("Some Title");
```

This line changes the *user* object too

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). We can't help you with code we cannot see.

Comment: *"To avoid same reference problem, I created both of them from a JSON string using Google Gson."* That's a bit round-about, if all you need to do is make a copy of something.

Comment: You have to make a deep copy. That means you have to recursively make copies of the properties of the copied object aswell. If it its just the List you can use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: Please post the code of the class User, maybe you defined Degrees list as static?

Answer (score 0):

Both Degrees objects must be different instances, created by two `new Degrees()` (or independent deserialisations). Maybe you did

```
User editedUser = new User();
editedUser.setDegrees(user.getDegrees());
```

If this leads to a sharing of the internal degrees of `user`, `getDegrees` is done 
dangerously, exposing an internal list.

```
editedUser.getDegrees().addAll(user.getDegrees());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You did a shallow copy, ie. the Lists are copies and they refer to exactly the same objects. What you need is make a deep copy in this case, ie. not just copy the lists but each element within them.